# How did Mega-Lo-Mania's save state system work?

Tags: game-cartridge

To continue a game in Mega-Lo-Mania (AKA Tyrants) on the Sega Megadrive/Genesis, you would enter an eight digit code into the interface and then you could resume a session.

Presumably, the code contains information about the state of the game since neither the Megadrive nor the cartridge had no means to persist data for the game between power cycles. I also suspect that the code includes a sort of parity check to prevent random codes from being used.

What is the breakdown of the Mega-Lo-Mania code data format, and how can a custom save state be generated to target a particular world and set of circumstances?

Comment: Do you think the code contains state information, or is it just a lookup table? There might only be 40 bits of information, less any CRC, which doesn't sound enough for a full game state. However, if there was a code for the start of each epoch, plus a bit of extra information for the number of men left over, this might be enough to restart a level?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The password is made of 11 capital letters (A to Z) and encodes the following values:

- A value from 0 to 3 that indicates the selected player (red, green, yellow, or blue).
- A value from 0 to 9 that indicates the starting epoch (1st to 9th epoch or Megalomania).
- The number of men, from 0 to 999.
- Four unknown values, each from 0 to 49. (I haven't played the game to confirm where these values are used, but a hypothesis is that some of these values may be related to the number of men you put into suspended animation in the 7th, 8th, and 9th epochs. In the password lists below, the unknown values are zero until the passwords for starting on the 8th epoch.)

The encoding process includes the following kinds of steps:

- The last character of the password is a checksum generated with addition and exclusive or operations.
- The bits of data are obfuscated with bit rotation and exclusive or operations.
- Some of the unused bits that would have normally been zero are instead filled with amounts based on counting the number of "1" bits in segments of the data.

I created a simple [Mega-Lo-Mania Password Generator](https://rnhart.net/mega-lo-mania-pw.htm) in HTML and JavaScript. Here are some JavaScript snippets adapted from it that show the encoding process:

```
player = 0;
epoch = 0;
men = 100;
w = 0;  // unknown values
x = 0;
y = 0;
z = 0;

d0 = 40 * men + 4 * epoch + player;
d1 = 50 * w + x;
d2 = 50 * y + z;

k = d0;  // checksum
k ^= 0x2435;
k += d1;
k ^= 0x2435;
k += d2;
k ^= 0x2435;
k &= 0xFFFF;
k %= 26;

d1 = (d0 & 0xFFF) ^ d1;
d2 = ( (d0 >> 3) & 0xFFF ) ^ d2;
d0 = ( ((d0 & 0xF800) >> 11) | ((d0 & 0x07FF) << 5) ) ^ 0x2435;

d1 = ((count_bits(d1) & 3) << 12) | d1;
d2 = ((count_bits(d2) & 3) << 12) | d2;

password = "";
password += base26(d0, 4);  // 4 letters, A to Z, little-endian
password += base26(d1, 3);  // 3 letters
password += base26(d2, 3);  // 3 letters
password += base26(k,  1);  // 1 letter
```

Here are some example passwords and the data they contain.

From IGN [Genesis Cheats - MEGAloMANIA: Jikuu Daisenryaku](https://www.ign.com/wikis/gen-cheats/MEGAloMANIA:_Jikuu_Daisenryaku_Cheats):

| Password | Player | Epoch | Men | Unknown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `NZUCWTIAEHV` | Red | 2nd | 148 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `ARTCKXKNMND` | Red | 3rd | 184 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `YLGBUMQZKNL` | Red | 4th | 176 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `IHUBUGQULTB` | Red | 5th | 172 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `COCAKLDWEBX` | Red | 6th | 160 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `EBWROLJUHNJ` * |  |  |  |  |
| `EBWAOLJUHNJ` ** | Red | 7th | 159 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `QPIAXODAHHM` | Red | 8th | 163 | 5 1 0 0 |
| `ZBLDRNIHGTY` | Red | 9th | 143 | 5 1 0 0 |
| `CPFDVMRBYST` | Red | Megalomania | 100 | 10 1 0 1 |

* sic, invalid password
** corrected

From GameFAQs [Tyrants: Fight Through Time (Genesis) - Cheats](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/genesis/586569-tyrants-fight-through-time/cheats):

| Password | Player | Epoch | Men | Unknown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `SIZCSVLOPNL` | Red | 1st | 200 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `SMLCUQKDKHH` | Red | 2nd | 999 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `WQICAUWQIBN` | Red | 3rd | 999 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `UVICOPEQIBJ` | Red | 4th | 999 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `SAJCSPEFKHV` | Red | 5th | 999 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `QFJCKRKFKHR` | Red | 6th | 999 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `OKJCAQEGKHX` | Red | 7th | 999 | 0 0 0 0 |
| `MPJCDWEGKHK` | Red | 8th | 999 | 5 1 0 0 |
| `KUJCTYQVLNW` | Red | 9th | 999 | 5 1 0 0 |
| `IZJCJKXGKHD` | Red | Megalomania | 999 | 10 1 0 1 |

Comment: Amazing work. I deleted my answer, as it couldn't have been more wrong! When the question specified 8 digits, I didn't believe that was enough bits to allow for meaningful game state plus a checksum to avoid random guesses, so I just assumed they were hard coded (like Desert Strike etc).

Comment: Very well done, I am amazed at your effort!

Comment: Having played around a little, I strongly suspect that the remaining four values are relevant to how many men have been "put aside" for the final battle in the previous couple of epochs. 49 = max 999. An interesting situation results when all are set to zero: you play the game with no men, and none of the AI players have any men, and the game cannot be won or lost.